# C++ move semantics and code duplication as a result of method overloading

Tags: c++

Before I begin, I didn't find anything that completely explains my question in an other stackoverflow post so I decided to create my own. Apologies if it is already answered somewhere else(kindly point me to the existing post if it does exist).

Lets say we have the following two methods inside of a class:

```
int do_stuff(Thing& thing){ /* Do stuff... */} // L-value version
int do_stuff(Thing&& thing){ /* Do stuff... */} // R-value version
```

From what I have read, modern C++ has pretty much abandoned this kind of logic and it is recommending to just pass the `Thing` by value and let the compiler do it's magic. My question is, If I want to have two separate methods that explicitly handles L-values/R-values and avoid code duplication, which of the following is best(performance wise and as in best practice)?

```
int do_stuff(Thing& thing){ return do_stuff(std::move(thing)); } // The L-value version uses the R-value one
```

Or

```
int do_stuff(Thing&& thing){ return do_stuff(thing); } // The R-value version uses the L-value one since text is an L-value inside the scope of do_stuff(Thing&&)
```

Edit: The purpose of the question is for me to understand this simple case of move semantics and not to create a valid C++ API.

Edit #2: The `print` and `std::string` parts of the question are used as an example. They can be anything.

Edit #3: Renamed the example code. The methods do modify the Thing object.

Comment: Does `print` actually modify `text`? That would seem a bit unusual.

Comment: Please clarify. Why do you want to have 2 overloads when you want them to do the same thing? Passing by const ref or by value seems like the idiomatic approach.

Comment: @juanchopanza It does not. But the print method was used as an example. It could be anything.

Comment: Also, the semantics of the two overloads are different. One says "modify this thing for me, and I will use the modifications", and the other one says "take this thing and do with it what you will, I will not use it anymore so I don't care".

Comment: @theVoid If it does not modify, then you should not be passing non-const ref.

Comment: Can you answer the code duplication part in this specific example? This is the thing I am trying to understand. I know that the function API is ill-formed but it was used as a means to express my question.

Comment: The question can't be answered because it isn't clear that there would be duplicated code, given the different semantics of the overloads.

Comment: @juanchopanza Let's say the string is modified for some reason(again it doesn't have to be an std::string nor a print method).

Comment: Is it any more clear now?

Comment: You changed the question so that some answers became almost irrelavant.

Comment: @theVoid I edited my anwer according to your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in performance. `std::move` does nothing but casts the type  of its argument, so a smart compiler will omit the call to `std::move`, and even omit the redundant call to `do_stuff`. [You can see](https://godbolt.org/z/KTagHq) under `-O2`, in either case, GCC compiles the `do_stuff` that calls the other `do_stuff` to a simple `jmp` command to the other `do_stuff`.

So it is opinion-based which way is better. I personally like the second way because it is shorter.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason this was extremely confusing to me.

Answer (score 4):

If `print` doesn't change anything and only prints the string, it's best to take a `const std::string &` as `const std::string &` is able to bind to both  lvalues and rvalues.

```
int print(const std::string& text) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing an argument by value does **not** mean it can't be an `rvalue` reference. The `&&` just means that the parameter **has** to be an `rvalue` reference. Not having `&&` **doesn't** mean the parameter **can't** be an `rvalue` reference.

When the argument is only *used* by the function, and with that, I mean if it's not modified, the best way to declare your function is:

```
int do_stuff(const Thing& thing);
```

That way, it is very clear to the reader that `thing` won't be modified. For most of the other cases, you should simply declare your function as:

```
int do_stuff(Thing thing);
```

passing the parameter by value, and not by reference or `rvalue` reference.

It used to be common to write code like this:

```
int do_stuff(Thing& thing)
{
    /* change thing so that the caller can use the changed thing */
    return success; // where success is an int
}
```

However, nowadays, it is often preferred to return the modified thing:

```
Thing do_stuff(Thing thing) { /* return modified thing */ }
```

In the example above:

```
int do_stuff(Thing thing);
```

the caller decides whether or not `thing` should be a copy:

```
do_stuff(my_thing); // copy - I need the original my_thing
do_stuff(std::move(thing)); // no copy - I don't need the original my_thing
```

Note that this declaration of `do_stuff` covers both of your versions:

```
int do_stuff(Thing&);
int do_stuff(Thing&&);
```

That said, you **almost never** need functions like:

```
int do_stuff(Thing&&);
```

unless for objects which cannot be copied like `stream` objects.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me demystify some things about move semantics.